# Find $c$ if $a,b, \; c$ satisfy $c = (a+bi)^3 - 107i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Find $c$ if $a,b, \; c$ are positive integers which satisfy $c = (a+bi)^3 - 107i$

I can try expanding the cube, but that seems too direct. What other ways are there to go about this?

Comment: Presumably, $a,b,c$ are supposed to be integers?

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean with 'find $c$' when you already have $c=$something.

Comment: Presumably, that can be written as "find an integer $c$ such that $c+107i$ is a cube in the Gaussian integers." @Crostul

Comment: Edited appropriately

Comment: The coefficient of $i$ in $(a+bi)^3$ is a multiple of $b$.

Comment: In my opinion the simplest way to do it is expanding the cube. You find that the only solution is $a=6, b=1, c= 198$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $c \in \mathbb Z$, the right-hand side must have an imaginary component of $0$. Expanding, we get

$$c = (a+bi)^3 - 107i = (a^3-3ab^2) + (3a^2b-b^3-107)i$$

Therefore $3a^2b-b^3-107 = 0$, which implies that $(3a^2-b^2)b=107$. Since $107$ is prime, we conclude that $b$ is either $1$ or $107$.

Case 1: $b=1$. Then $3a^2 -1 = 107$, so $a=6$.

Case 2: $b=107$. Then $3a^2 - 107^2 = 1$. But there is no integer solution to this equation.

Therefore the unique solution is $(a,b,c) = (6,1,198)$.

Comment: In what does this differ from the other given solution?

Comment: @egreg The other solution originally said to solve by trial and error, so I wrote this to show how to solve by factoring 107.

Comment: I see; so +1 to you.

Comment: This is clearer than the other solution. Thanks!

Comment: @meownyaa You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

$$\Im((a+bi)^3-107i)=3a^2b-b^3-107=0,$$
$$(3a^2-b^2)b=107.$$
$107$ is a prime, so $b=1\lor b=107$.
$$b=1\implies a=6,$$
$$b=107\implies 3a^2=11450\text{ (reject)}.$$
$$c=(a+bi)^3-107i=198.$$

Comment: I do not understand this solution. What does $\Im$ and $\Re$ mean?

Comment: $\Im(z)$ is the imaginary part of the complex number $z$, and $\Re(z)$ is the real part. It does seem unnecessary notation for this problem... @meownyaa

Comment: @Thomas: the goal is to concisely express that $c$ is real, so that the imaginary part vanishes.

Comment: I understand now! Thank you!